# How to get all user's email from Azure Active Directory using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying get list of emails of users from Azure Active Directory using ASP.NET MVC. I do have Azure AD information. I've tried to find a  solution, but most of the answers are for ASP.NET Core - not for ASP.NET  MVC.

So get all emails from Azure AD and display it in dropdown (select2).

Comment: You can probably look to using Microsoft Graph. Microsoft provide a pretty good getting started guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.